# Different settings URLS in django

Tags: python, django

I usually use the `SITE_URL` in my settings file. I noticed someone else's settings file with the following three items:

- `URL_ROOT`
- `SITE_URL_ROOT`
- `URL_ROOT_SECURE`

Why would a URL_ROOT_SECURE be needed -- shouldn't this be handled in the apache config? And what is the differerence between the two ROOTs here?

Comment: Are these settings part of project's settings.py or its user defined custom app specific settings?

Comment: Part of django's `settings.py` file.

Comment: In which version of django that project is in?  Please use this command-:

python manage.py diffsettings

See this link for your reference.

https://pythonhosted.org/django_simple_feedback/ref/django-admin.html#diffsettings


Please paste the output